# How can I measure the shock absorption of a key switch?

Tags: keyboard, ergonomics, measurement

One common criteria when choosing a keyboard is looking at the shock absorption of its key switches. How can I measure the shock absorption of a key switch?

E.g., the actuation force can be measured by adding some weights such as coins on the key cap.

Comment: I'd highly recommend also posting this in the physics SE. It's good here, but over there they can also reference the way that shock, shock absorption, and damping are measured in theory and in other engineering applications.